# rvalue arg is binding to lvalue overloaded function through std::forward

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand rvalue and std::forward nuances.
I made a simple following program and I am expecting that
"process:: rvalue is called" should be printed as str3 is an rvalue.
But the result is "process:: lvalue is called".
Please explain the reason.

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
void process(string& obj)
{
    cout<<"process:: lvalue is called"<<endl;
}
void process(string&& obj)
{
    cout<<"process:: rvalue is called"<<endl;
}
template<typename T>
void func(T&& obj)
{
    process(std::forward<T>(obj));
}
int main()
{
    string str1 = "abc";
    string str2 = "def";
    string&& str3 = str1 + str2;
    func(str3);
    cout<<"str3 is "<<str3<<endl;
 
    return 0;
```

Trying to understand rvalue,forward nuances.

Comment: "`str3` is an rvalue..." Incorrect. The **variable** `str3` has declared type "rvalue reference to `std::string`". The **expression** `str3` has type `std::string` (expressions never have reference types) and value category is lvalue and fowarded as a lvalue. `std::forward` is doing the correct thing because it gives you the same result as `process(str3)`. This is certainly another dup.